# Passing more parameters to getView() method in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, parameters, android-arrayadapter, getview

In my MyAdapter class, I am passing in the `(Context context, String[] values)` parameters, as shown below in my code. I want to use the `String[] values` variable in the getView() method. Is there anyway to pass this variable into the getView() method?

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_layout_2, values);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater theInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View theView = theInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout_2, parent, false);
        String tvShow = getItem(position);
        TextView theTextView = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        theTextView.setText(tvShow);
        ImageView theImageView = (ImageView) theView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        theImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot);
        return theView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could store an instance variable for your items

```
private final String[] items;
```

Then your constructor would look like

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_layout_2, values);
    this.items = values;
}
```

and have a getter such as

```
public String[] getItems() {
    return items;
}
```